# Generate a matrix by using a row vector defined by rand

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector

```
q=randn(1,200)
```

I want to generate a 60 by 200 matrix by generating rand(1,200) 60 times and adding it with another vector x of size 1 by 200.

The code I wrote:

```
n=1:200;

sig=1.34;

x=trnd(nu,1,length(n));

for i=1:60

    q=randn(1,length(n));

    s=x+sig.*q;

end
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The code doesn't work, it does work but doesn't do what you want? It is inefficient? -- Currently someone guessed what you needed (perhaps he is right) but please make sure that it is very clear what you are asking in this or future questions.

Comment: Here is a hint as to why this probably doesn't do what you want: You overwrite s each time. You may need something like `s(:,i)` to make it work. That being said, the existing answer would be a better way to get that result.

Answer (score 1):

```
    q = randn(60,200);
    x = trnd(nu,1, 200);
    x2 = repmat(x,[60 1]);
    s = q + sig*x2;
```

Or, as suggested in the comments:

```
    s = bsxfun(@plus, sig*q, x);
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `q = randn(60,200)*sig`

Comment: rather use `bsxfun` i.e. `s = bsxfun(@plus, q, x)`. Also note from MATLAB 2016b on you can just do `s = q + x` (unless backwards compatibility is an issue).

Comment: @Dan: Broadcasting! Nice tip. I'll need to check out the prerelease.